# mteTrigger snmpTrap not getting fired when NTP is down

Tags: linux, redhat, snmp, chrony, snmptrapd

I'm trying to generate DISMAN EVENT whenever NTP is down by extending snmp. Have written shell script to extend mib. Using NTPv4-MIB https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5907.
In the custom pass-though script I'm setting NTPv4-MIB::ntpEntStatusCurrentMode to 2 if ntpstat commands returns 1.

```
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
pass .1.3.6.1.2.1.197.1 /bin/sh /usr/share/snmp/snmpconf-data/snmpd-data/exampleScriptNtp.sh
monitor -r 60 -u snmpuser  -o NTPv4-MIB::ntpEntNotifMessage "System not in sync with NTP" NTPv4-MIB::ntpEntStatusCurrentMode == 2
trap2sink x.x.x.x public
```

But when I remove `/var/lib/net-snmp/.snmp-exec-cache` file traps gets flooded at trapsync like below.

```
13:45:14.812399 IP x.x.x.x.47674 > hostname.snmptrap:  V2Trap(190)  system.sysUpTime.0=12688 S:1.1.4.1.0=88.2.0.1 8" System not in sync with NTP" 88.2.1.2.0="" 88.2.1.3.0="" 88.2.1.4.0=197.1.2.1 88.2.1.5.0=2 197.1.5.1=[noSuchInstance]
13:45:14.816145 IP x.x.x.x.47674 > hostname.snmptrap:  V2Trap(190)  system.sysUpTime.0=12688 S:1.1.4.1.0=88.2.0.1 8" 88.2.System not in sync with NTP 1.2.0="" 88.2.1.3.0="" 88.2.1.4.0=197.1.2.1 88.2.1.5.0=2 197.1.5.1=[noSuchInstance]
```

I can see that event entry has been created from snmp debug logs. But trap is not fired

```
disman:event:conf: _BSystem not in sync with NTP: Bool (NTPv4-MIB::ntpEntStatusCurrentMode, 2, 2)
trace: build_oid_noalloc(): mib.c, 3896:
build_oid_noalloc: generated: .10.115.110.109.112.100.46.99.111.110.102.83.121.115.116.101.109.32.110.111.116.32.105.110.32.115.121.110.99.32.119.105.116.104.32.78.84.80
trace: mteTrigger_createEntry(): disman/event/mteTrigger.c, 98:
disman:event:table: Create trigger entry (snmpd.conf, System not in sync with NTP)
trace: build_oid_noalloc(): mib.c, 3896:
build_oid_noalloc: generated: .10.115.110.109.112.100.46.99.111.110.102.83.121.115.116.101.109.32.110.111.116.32.105.110.32.115.121.110.99.32.119.105.116.104.32.78.84.80
trace: netsnmp_tdata_add_row(): helpers/table_tdata.c, 264:
tdata_add_row: added row (0x55fc4a3c33a0)
trace: mteTrigger_createEntry(): disman/event/mteTrigger.c, 148:
disman:event:table: Trigger entry created
```